# Mass image download from yfrog

Tags: windows-7, images, download

I want to download around 500 photos from a user account on [yfrog.com](http://yfrog.com). The photos are located under the URL in the following format:

```
http://yfrog.com/user/<username>/photos
```

Is there to bulk download these files? I tried the trial version of "Bulk Image Downloader" but it couldn't locate the photos.

Comment: What is the exact link for the pictures?

Comment: It's a gallery of a friend of mine. I'd better not give the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget + 'for' command + batch file

1) Download wget (Google, "wget.exe for windows")

2) Create new text file download.cmd:

```
@echo off
set LIST=1 2 3
set LIST=%LIST% 4 5 6
for %i in (%LIST%) do (
    wget.exe http://yfrog.com/user/aaa/photos/%i.jpg
)
```

4) Edit download.cmd to your liking. Of course you need to get list of image ids somewhere (1 2 3 4 5 6 in this example), but I believe it's beyond the scope of the question.

5) Save download.cmd to the same folder as wget.exe and run it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting the list of image IDs is crucial and the core of my question. I need a total solution which can acquire the image IDs automatically. If I could do that, I wouldn't ask this question.